# Writing "\\" inside a string

Tags: c#, string

I want to do something like:

```
string s = "\\blabla";
```

when you write "\" it means there will only be a single '\'. How do I write the string so there will actually be 2 '\' meaning "\" ?

Comment: Do you mean a _backslash_?

Comment: Have you tried your own code?

Comment: Test your string literal in the C# REPL.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This works without a problem:

```
string s = "//blabla";
```

If you mean the backslash instead, you can use a verbatim string literal (using the `@` symbol to avoid processing escape symbols):

```
string s = @"\\blabla";
```

Alternatively you can escape the escape character itself:

```
string s = "\\\\blabla";
```

Answer (score 7):

`'/'` is not the escape char, so you can simply write `"//"`

The escape char is `'\'` and, to use it properly, you can refer to the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) instructions.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
string s = @"\\blabla";
```

The '@' symbol treats whatever follows it as a verbatim string literal (ie: you won't need to worry about escape characters within the string).

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean `\` not `/`.

You could escape the `\` with another backslash `"\\\\"` or you could use a string literal `@"\\"`

Answer (score 0):

You may use @ before strings to avoid having to escape special characters.

> The advantage of @-quoting is that escape sequences are not processed,
>   which makes it easy to write

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe(v=vs.71).aspx